# Find primary current in 3 phase transformer

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, three-phase

[image]

I am really confused with the above problem.

I get the logic of the solution

Since,the line voltage ratio is 2. So, current will be half. Thus 50.

But I am confused should we take +30 or -30.

Shouldn't it depend on the connection whether it is Yd1 or Yd11.

Please help me in understanding this concept.

---

### -- EDIT --

I was trying to draw some phasors which I have attached below

[image]

Assuming IA winding and Iab winding are in phase

In this case taking Ib = 100 <0 gives me IA = 50 <30

Please help me with current phasors, I am really confused.

Comment: R loads give same I phasors as V phasors. Wye the confusion? https://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/tech/threeph.htm

Comment: https://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/tech/wyedelta.gif

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975, just tell me will IA be in phase with Iab or 180 out of phase with Iab ??

Comment: Look at the picture do you see 180 or 0 deg? No becuase WYE primary to Delta secondary is rotated -30 degrees

Comment: but unlike analog clock and CW  Notation for + phase , + angle is CCW rising above the zero axis at 3 o'clock

Comment: Is A the correct option ??

Comment: It is a step-down  transformer from 230V to 115V but delta secondary so \$\sqrt{3}\$ bigger than if it were WYE, so how do you think>? are you thinking?

Comment: You gave a detailed explanation, Thanks for that. But you didn't answer my question will IA and Iab be in phase in the diagram I have drawn. And I am not able to understand that 6 ways of delta wiring thing.

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 please check my answer. I think I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A balanced (positive sequence) three phase AC voltage source is connected to a balanced, Y-connected load through a \$Y-\Delta\$ transformer as shown in the signal.
The line to line voltage testing is 230V on the Y side and 115V on the \$\Delta\$-side. If the magnetizing current is neglected and \$I_s=100A,  \Phi=0\$, then whar is the value of \$I_p\$ in ameres?
[image]

After understanding the connection, now we will try to draw voltage and current phasors.

Since, the line voltage ratio is 2. So, we can conclude that the magnitude of primary line current will be 50. Now, we will try to get its phase using current phasor.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**WYE to DELTA or DELTA to WYE results in positive or + 30 deg shift.**
where **a** leads **b** leading **c**

> Yes it matters how it is wired. There is **never** any phase displacement or shift between two common windings, but there **MAY** be a phase displacement or shift between the line voltages of two transformers depending on **how** the windings are connected.

In this example B+ goes to A' or A'-B  or C'-A
**Yd11**  with 30 deg lead. **(secondary leads primary by 30 deg.)** *and primary WYE lags secondary DELTA*

### [image] [image]

Why does math use CCW for positive angles and clocks rotate the opposite direction?

... because in math everyone uses Archimedes and Cartesian standards with right axis as + and vertical axis at top is +ve  ( same in schematics for V+ to top)
[image] [image]

Rotating a circle past any reference point in the orientation as you are told (CCW is positive) then Delta to WYE or WYE to DELTA if in same sequence given  results in 30 rotation to left or CCW or POSITIVE 30 deg.

Positive angles in Trigonometry   oppose direction of clock. It does not mean we go backward in time.  The cicle rotation std is also show here as CCW for positive degrees when rotating the circle past any reference point.

[image][image]

See again for **b** to lag **a** the triangle must be rotated CCW for POSITIVE ANGLES with positive time. \$\phi=\omega t\$